# Can I use GMail to manage my emails?

Tags: google, email, google-workspace, gmail

Say I buy a domain `foo.com` - can I easily use GMail to receive and send emails from an address of that domain. For example, `admin@foo.com`?

Is this possible or do I have to install a mail server on my VPS? I would prefer something free.

Comment: Belongs at webapps.

Comment: Do you need to send mail from your VPS through Google Apps for Business, or will you only need to send and receive through the Gmail-style interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Gmail if you sign up for Google Apps. You can find the free version here: http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Gmail you can click on your setting gears icon click the Accounts and Import tab, and you will see an option called under the `Send mail as:` section called `Add another email address you own` here you can add your own email address to use sending from gmail but as your@domain.com

zoho.com has free mail hosting for up to 3 accounts

Answer (score -1):

No you cannot use GMail to:

> ...receive and send emails from an address of that domain.

You cannot receive e-mail via GMail that is directed to your domain unless you have a catch-all forwarding setup which requires a mail server.

Answer (score -2):

To receive E-mails you will need to install mail server on your vps. You can either add e-mail account as pop or imap to your gmail. To send E-mail you can either use your own outgoing server (smtp.foo.com You will need to configure it in Gmail)or gmail's outgoing server.